# How can I make RSS link bold?

Tags: css, text, rss

On my blog page, I have some form text that says "Subscribe in a reader." I would like this to be the same weight/font/size/etc as the text above that says "Subscribe via Email:" I would also like to add a horizontal line dividing these two sections of the form.

http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/blog/
[CODE]

```
<p><a Style="padding-left: 13px;" href="feeds.feedburner.com/Blog-JeffreyDowellPhotography"; rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml"><img src="//feedburner.google.com/fb/images/pub/feed-icon16x16.png" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle;border:0"/></a>&nbsp;<a href="feeds.feedburner.com/Blog-JeffreyDowellPhotography"; rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml">Subscribe in a reader</a></p>
```

Comment: Probably worth putting that in a fiddle so this question remains useful when that site goes down!

Comment: You'd be better off not providing a link to your site but rather the actual code you are using.

Comment: why would my site go down?

Comment: @JeffDowell Your site could go down for many reasons. Maybe you decide to change the name, or maybe your hosting company has an outage of some sort. Either way, it's usually best practice to include code here and/or on a JSFiddle so regardless of the site's status, others can see the process involved in solving your issue.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being a noob! All sites will go down eventually. This site exists to help future visitors with the same problem as much as the person posting the original question.

Comment: @JeffDowell Like Poldie said, nothing wrong with being a noob! I'd recommend including your code in your question, rather than here in the comments. That way it will be much easier to read.

Comment: You need to add 4 spaces before each line of code. Read here to see how to format your posts: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: The code is now in the question area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the font issue, give your `<a>` tag an `id` or `class` then style it using CSS. Here's an example:

HTML

```
<a href="..." rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" id="rss_link">
  Subscribe in a reader
</a>
```

CSS

```
#rss_link {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

In order to add a border, you will also need to give and `id` or `class` to the `<p>` element that contains the RSS link, then use the following to apply the border:

HTML

```
<p id="my_border">
  <a style="padding-left: 13px;" href="..." rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml">
    <img src="..." alt="" style="vertical-align:middle;border:0">
  </a>&nbsp;
  <a href="..." rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml">
    Subscribe in a reader
  </a>
</p>
```

CSS

```
#my_border {
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

***Update***

To target the "Subscribe in a reader" text use the following:

```
.sqs-block-content p a {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

To add the border, use the following:

```
.sqs-block-content form {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Now, I don't know what the rest of the HTML is like on other pages, and since these are classes, other elements may be affected by the above CSS. Keep an eye out for any unwanted changes...

Comment: This is way over my head, this is a template based site from squarespace with lots of css that i added to customize it. Im afraid i dont know how to give ID and CLASS stuff. Thank you though.

Comment: Do you have access to the HTML files?

Comment: no, i can only add html into a "Header Code injection" page. I can right-click and do an "inspect element" and copy i suppose?

Comment: Then you would just be duplicating the elements on the page it sounds like. Based on your limited access to the HTML files, you'll have to target the elements a little differently. See the update in my answer above.